# Swift type does not conform to 'Decodable'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to write a UserModel class to help with my JSON response decoding, and am running into the following error:

`Type 'UserModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

My UserModel struct is as follows.

```
struct UserModel: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let email: String
    let tokenIssuedAt: Int
    let createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String
    let settings: Settings

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tokenIssuedAt = "token_issued_at"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
    
    struct Settings: Codable {
        var wishlists, collection, findable: Bool
    }
}
```

If I remove the settings variable from this struct as well as the settings struct this error goes away, but given the Settings is codable, I am confused as to why this is causing my UserModel struct to break.

I've tried updating the coding keys to the following:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case email
    case tokenIssuedAt = "token_issued_at"
    case createdAt = "created_at"
    case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    case settings
}
```

As well as adding an initializing decoder such as:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    settings = try container.decode(Settings.self, forKey: .settings)
}
```

However I then get the following error message:

> Type 'UserModel' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
> Type 'UserModel' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Is this coming from a mistake I've made in the coding keys, the settings struct, or something else I may have overlooked when stubbing this Struct?

The JSON I am trying to decode looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1cc02c5f-2cb3-4546-a2d7-a824188e667d",
        "email": "trenton@example.com",
        "token_issued_at": 1676418140,
        "created_at": "2023-02-09T01:51:08.733Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-14T23:46:14.136Z",
        "settings": {
            "collection": false,
            "wishlist": false,
            "findable": true
        }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach,

```
struct UserModel: Codable, Identifiable {  // <-- here
    
    let id: String
    let email: String
    let tokenIssuedAt: Int
    let createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String
    let settings: Settings

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tokenIssuedAt = "token_issued_at"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case id, email, settings   // <-- here
    }
    
    struct Settings: Codable {
        var wishlist, collection, findable: Bool  // <-- here wishlist, not s
    }
    }
```

Note, if you really need the `Hashable` in `UserModel` put it also in the `Settings`

Comment: This solved my problem, however i'm curious why the error message is coming from Decodable and not an indication that Hashable is the culprit. Any ideas here?

Comment: updated my answer with another typo, use `wishlist` not `wishlists` in your `Settings` , it needs to match the json data **exactly**. Note you are also missing the last `}` in your json data.

Comment: @Anon I've tried to explain that in my answer. And thanks @workingdogsupportUkraine! That is a nice spot! I did not realise that.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt doesn't work because you only specified a subset of the keys you want to decode in the `CodingKeys` enum. To the compiler, this means that you *only* want to decode those keys in the JSON. However, if only those keys are decoded, then `id`, `email` and `settings` will not be initialised to anything when decoding, which is against the rules of Swift.

When you added all the keys into `CodingKeys`, there is still the error that says `UserModel` does not conform to `Hashable` and `Equatable`. This is because `Settings` does not conform to either of those. In order to automatically generate a conformance for `Hashable`, all the members need to be `Hashable`.

Either making `Settings` conform to `Hashable`

```
struct Settings: Hashable, Codable {
    var wishlist, collection, findable: Bool
}
```

Or making `UserModel` *not* conform to `Hashable`,

```
struct UserModel: Codable, Identifiable {
```

will fix the error.

You should remove the `init(from:)` that you added, as that *only* decodes `settings`. You can just use the one that Swift automatically generates.

In fact, you can also remove the coding keys enum in `UserModel`. Mapping coding keys from snake case can be done by the `convertFromSnakeCase` option in the decoder. You can just set this in the decoder when decoding:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```